# Get Firefox version as root

Tags: linux, bash, macos, firefox, sudo

I have an installation script that I'd like to run on macOS/Linux.

Mid-installation, I need to detect the currently installed Firefox version to decide whether or not to use a deprecated feature (i.e. `AutoConfig`) versus a modern feature (i.e. `policies.json`).

- For Windows, I have logic to parse the Firefox version from the registry.  This works fine.
- On macOS/Linux I want to parse the output of `firefox --version` however when `firefox` sees the script running as `root` it complains:

> Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported.  (`$HOME` is `/Users/foo` which is owned by `foo`.)

I can use `sudo -u $USER firefox --version` but this seems like it will have scalability issues with systems that don't have `sudo` enabled.  Is there another way to get the version without launching the process as a regular user?  Is there an undocumented override flag?  I've tried `--headless` to no avail.

Comment: If there are problems with the question, please explain to improve the quality of questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the following is a viable workaround for running `firefox --version` as root.

```
HOME=/tmp XAUTHORITY=/tmp firefox --version
```

As far as I know, `/tmp` should always be owned by `root`, but if there are exceptions, please propose a better path so that this solution can be improved.